# Javascript scope question - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, scope, google-chrome-extension

```
for(var p = 0; p < xmls.length; p++) {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(xmls[p]);
    feed.load(function(result) {
//code
```

In the above code, if I output p outside of the feed.load function, I correctly see that p iterates.  However, if I output p inside that function (where I need to access it), It remains at 2 (which happens to be the length of the array "xmls").  I know this is a scope issue, but not how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see also [javascript+closures+loops](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+closures+loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new scope, which means a new function.

```
for(var p = 0; p < xmls.length; p++) {
    (function(p) {
         var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(xmls[p]);
         feed.load(function(result) {
                       // use p
         });
     })(p);
}
```